# How to remove additional printed line in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to print a string in groovy but the results show an additional empty line below the printed string. Here are my codes:

```
String strg = "11110111"
println "strg:"+strg
```

The expected results should be "11110111" but the result has an additional empty line below it. May I know what went wrong and how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `print` instead of `println`.

`println` adds a new line at the end of printed string.